# How do I remove duplicate attributes from an array based on fields of the objects in the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates, field

I'm using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4  I have an array of objects, each object having the fields

```
name
member_id
```

I wish to scan through my array and eliminate duplicate items, taht is, items whose fields "name" and "member_id" already match something else in teh array.  How do I do this?  I realize I can check if the array already contains an item by using

```
results.any?{|a| a.name.eql?(name) && a.member_id == member_id}
```

But I'm unsure how to use the above to eliminate duplicates.  Also, if there are duplicates, I still want to keep one of the items with the unique name/member_id combination.

Comment: It'd help if you provided input data and your expected output. Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) is an option.  For instance, suppose I want to compare the subarray elements in the following by their values at subindices 0 and 2.  I can create a comparison object comprised of those items and use it with `uniq`'s block option:

```
a = [
  ['one', 1, 1],
  ['two', 2, 2],
  ['one', 2, 1],
  ['two', 2, 2],
  ['one', 1, 2],
]

p a.uniq { |elt| [elt[0], elt[2]] }  # => [["one", 1, 1], ["two", 2, 2], ["one", 1, 2]]
```